# Starting jms message driven channel adapter at runtime

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I have a web application running on tomcat with declared activemq consumer. Application works fine, but now I want to start consumer at runtime - so I declared control bus and send a message to this.

There is a piece of my code:

```
<channel id="controlChannel"/>

<control-bus input-channel="controlChannel"/>

<gateway service-interface="myApp.ControlGateway" default-request-channel="controlChannel"/>

<channel id="eventQueueChannel"/>

<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="eventQueueJMSIn"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        destination="eventQueue"
        channel="eventQueueChannel"
        auto-startup="false"
        acknowledge="transacted"
        concurrent-consumers="${concurrentConsumers:1}"
        max-concurrent-consumers="${maxConcurrentConsumers:10}"/>
```

Then I start this gateway by `controlBusGateway.sendCommand("@eventQueueJMSIn.start()");`.

The problem is that consumer can't connect to activemq. Moreover there is a problem with publisher too.

In conclusion, when everything starts automatically there is no problem. When I change consumer gateway to `auto-startup="false"`, then I can't send nor receive any message from activemq. But when I was testing this bug, I assume that if in activemq is enqueued message, it connect to it and everything goes right.

I am very suprised, that there are problems with publishers - I didn't change it. And I don't know why it sometimes works...

EDIT:

There is an error: 
"`org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory` cannot be cast to `org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory`" - it appears after changing `auto-startup` to false.

I saw also that  `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` returns `BundleDelegatingClassLoader` when everything is ok and `AppClassLoader` when exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not an overhead, then you can try using Camel Framework to achieve the described scenario.

Comment: Ok I'll try understand this Camel Framework, but anyone could know what is wrong with my code? I spent with this many hours and still don't know what is going on... It seems, that after disable `auto-startup` something goes wrong with `TransportFactory`

Comment: The code configuration that you've done for AMQ is good, no issue there. Camel may not fix all issues as this is classpath issue, besides bundling camel inside a war file may a completely different route. Before that suspect this could be an activemq-client jar issue. Can you please update what the version of AMQ broker, client jar you're using in the project.

Comment: I don't know if I search properly, but I thnk that version is 5.4.2. I use activeMQ in 5.13.0 version.

I fixed it now, changing classloader while I try to start activemq queue/topic and then return to old classloader. This isn't very good solution, but recently used in this project. I heard that this could be a problem with osgi integration.